# ionic: How to set login page's full height of screen without navbar?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I am working on a project using ionic framework. I want to remove the navigation section from top of login page and set its height full of device's height.

I removed header by setting this directive  **hide-nav-bar**

i.e `<ion-view title="Login" hide-nav-bar="true">`

Although it is removed but a white space in the place of navigation bar is showing. I want login page's height as full of screen's height but I am not getting any solution.

What is the best approach to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add hide-nav-bar="true" to your ion-view for that page.

```
<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true">
```

then add

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright I found solution myself. 
Just remove this class `class="has-header"` in the view were you don't want to show header. And it will be fixed.